# Combing multiple PNG files into one in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a product configurator app built in AngularJS. As options are selected, PNG images are stacked on top of each other to show the finished product. All images are the same size, but have different content.

Once the user is done configuring the options, I am looking for some way to combine all of the stacked images, into one new PNG file, and then save that file onto the server.

What are my options?

Comment: By "on top" do you mean overlayed or concatenated?

Comment: Also, how are the options selected, and how does the UI indicate some sort of order for the images to be combined?

Comment: Images are overlayed and positioned absolutely. Order is set with CSS/z-index.

Here's a link:

http://ssboatbuilder.wpengine.com

Comment: Do they have a `class` in common?

Comment: I can give them all the same class.

Comment: (edited above comment with link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Canvas API, this is quite easy to accomplish. The following assumes that all the displayed images have already fully loaded, though, so keep that in mind:

```
var combineImages = (function () {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  return function (className, callback) {
    var images = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className));

    images.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.style.zIndex - b.style.zIndex;
    });

    var width = canvas.width = images[0].naturalWidth;
    var height = canvas.height = images[0].naturalHeight;

    images.forEach(function (i) {
      ctx.drawImage(i, 0, 0, width, height);
    });

    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function () {
        callback(this);
      };
      image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
  }
})();

// combineImages('my-image-class', function (combinedImage) { ... });
```

#### References

- [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)
- [`HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)
- [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to use this method to save the newly created image to a directory on the server?

Comment: Yes. In that case you don't need to convert the `blob` to an `image`, just upload it directly with a POST request. You'll need to use a `multipart/form-data` encoding, or set the body directly as the blob binary data if that's the only thing you're uploading. However, since your image combinations have a finite amount, instead of wasting bandwidth uploading an image for every request, just look up the combination parameters or something and continue displaying it as an overlayed image, or if you just want the client to download it, just prompt for download rather than uploading first.

Comment: The problem is, I need to use that image's URL in an email. Upon form completion, emails are going out, and I want to have the finished product displayed in the email. Ultimately, what I need to do. I will look over what you sent me though. Thank you!

Comment: @ChadLamson you could precompute all the image combinations and save them to the server directory with image names based on the combination parameters

Comment: That was my first thought as well. The problem with that way is, more options will get added in the future, and will become a headache to maintain.

Comment: @ChadLamson then a hybrid approach: don't precompute, but _do_ save with specific image name on the server, and before uploading check if it already exists. If it does, save yourself the bandwidth which will become expensive over time. This works even if you add new parameters.

Comment: Ya.. I like that. Makes the most sense. Haven't worked with the canvas API before, so need to do some reading up... but will likely go this route.

Comment: @ChadLamson Was there anything else you need clarified, or have I sufficiently answered your question?

Answer (score -1):

You can look at some tools that can snap the content of the main div and convert it to png. I have converted it to pdf in past using pdfjs tool.